# 404 page when accessing http://localhost:1111/

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, port, http-status-code-404, odbc

Is the port 1111 reserved as a default port for the ODBC connection?

When I try to point my browser to 
http://localhost:1111/

it gives a 404 and not a page not found.

What is the best way to debug 404's from the ODBC ?

I am using Ubuntu and Apache (is Apache related to this?)

Comment: I don't know what being asked here. Is your apache running on port 1111? I think you should rephrase your question with an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just rephrased my question.  Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: This question can't be answered in it's current form. See all of @micah points below.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the port 1111 reserved as a default port for the ODBC connection?

no

> When I try to point my browser to http://localhost:1111/ it gives a 404 and not a page not found. What is the best way to debug 404's from the ODBC ?

404 is the HTTP response code for "page not found". Do you have a webserver running on port 1111 that you are trying to communicate with? I don't understand what that has to do with ODBC.

> I am using Ubuntu and Apache (is Apache related to this?)

I can not tell if this has anything to do with Apache with the information provided so far.